# Make footer stay at bottom of site unless site content goes past vertical window size

Tags: html, css, position

I have a footer for a website. The footer is an full width image and it's a gradient fade (black to transparent), the text is centered with `text-align: center`.

These below images show exactly what's going wrong.

- Footer misbehaving due in tall window: https://ibb.co/JH3rCdB
- Footer behaving properly due in short window: https://ibb.co/wCRnb8p

I don't want the footer to be always fixed at the bottom. So, I don't want `position: fixed`. If the window is not that tall, the footer should only be visible when the user scrolls all the way down. This is working fine.

The problem is when a user's browser window is very tall. The footer is then visible right under the site content, and then there's a gap between the footer and the bottom of the window.

How do I solve this?

Position: fixed is not what I want, and Position: sticky with bottom: 0px doesn't work right.